# What is correct Twilio AddOns syntax for php REST client?

Tags: php, rest, syntax, twilio

Beginner to both Twilio & php here:

I have: Twilio php helper, Twilio account, Whitepages Pro AddOn enabled for Lookups and have successfully retrieved "basic" lookup data, ie, "Carrier->Type" (the "basic" lookup does not use the AddOn)

I need: to use Twilio Rest Client with Whitepages Pro AddOn to retrieve other data, ie, "standard_address_line1", for an individual phone number. I do not want the $0.07 per call AddOn enabled for all incoming calls, although I was able to receive this data from the AddOn that way.

Twilio API Documentation is scant. Shows output format, but not REST Client request syntax: [WhitePagesPro AddOn Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/XB65bee4ad5be08e28368def1be1a3efee)

Here is what I tried:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$client = new Client(ACxxxxxxxxxx,Tokenxxxxxxxx);

$number = $client->lookups
    ->phoneNumbers("+1xxxxxxxxxx")
    ->fetch(
        array("AddOns" => "whitepages_pro_caller_id")
    );

echo $number->
  results->
  whitepages_pro_caller_id->
  result->
  results[0]->
  associated_locations[0]->
  standard_address_line1;

//This syntax works for 'basic' lookup
//Returns: "landline"
//
//$number = $client->lookups
//  ->phoneNumbers("+1xxxxxxxxxx")
//  ->fetch(
//      array("type" => "carrier")
//  );
//
//echo $number->carrier['type'];

?>
```

Throws error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException' with message 'Unknown property: results'

I'm way over my head, I don't know how to go about debugging this. Any Twilio experts?

Ideally I'd also like to know if it's possible to specify this particular data in the request vs traversing many levels of the response in order to get the data I need...

Comment: In [Twilio API documentation][1], found that Lookup also supports Twilio Add-ons, and "AddOns" query parameter under "HTTP GET" heading.

cURL (Postman) got data I need. Settings:

Type=GET, URI=lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+1xxxxxxxxx, Authorization=Basic, Username=ACxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Password=token_xxxxxxxxx, PARAMS Key=AddOns, Value=whitepages_pro_caller_id

Would still like to know if Twilio+php helper can be used to make this simpler than cURL (but this will do in the meantime!)

  [1]: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-query-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're very close with what you have there. The addOns results are actually returned in the `addOns` property of the number there. So, using your code, you can print the request SID of the call like this:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$client = new Client(ACxxxxxxxxxx,Tokenxxxxxxxx);

$number = $client->lookups
    ->phoneNumbers("+1xxxxxxxxxx")
    ->fetch(
        array("AddOns" => "whitepages_pro_caller_id")
    );

echo $number->addOns['results']['whitepages_pro_caller_id']['request_sid']
```

If you want to inspect the entire result, you can use `var_dump` to see the entire structure

```
var_dump($number->addOns['results']['whitepages_pro_caller_id'])
```

The structure will appear as it does in [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/XB65bee4ad5be08e28368def1be1a3efee#documentation) but it might be easier to see in the PHP output.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks so much! Got it working with your corrections!  Do you know if it's possible to pass a single parameter in the request so that only that parameter is returned? Not a big deal, but would be much cleaner.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Pass a single parameter to the API? What sort of thing do you want to return?

Comment: For example: I want the (whitepages pro) lookup to only return "standard_address_line1" and its value. I do know that some AddOns accept additional specific parameters, don't know about this one, and I can/will contact the vendor directly, just thought someone might know the answer. It would make the code to handle the response simpler, ie, instead of traversing down through the structure. Stated another way, I only need that one piece of data for this project, not all the other data the vendor provides.

Comment: or that's what "Runtime Request Parameters=none" means?! Not able to pass additional parameters. Maybe I was just hoping I missed something!

Comment: Oh, I see. No, you can't pre-select the part of the result you want in this add on. And that is what the lack of runtime request parameters means. I'd write a wrapper function around the API request so that you can just return the result you need from it each time. That would mean you only need to deal with the result traversal once in your application.